# Python Fire dynamic urls using multithreading

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm new to to Python-Threading, and I've gone through multiple posts but I really did not understand how to use it. However I tried to complete my task, and I want to check if I'm doing it with right approach.

Task is : 
Read big CSV containing around 20K records, fetch id from each record and fire an HTTP API call for each record of the CSV.

```
t1 = time.time()
file_data_obj = csv.DictReader(open(file_path, 'rU')) 
threads = []
for record in file_data_obj:
      apiurl = https://www.api-server.com?id=record.get("acc_id", "")
      thread = threading.Thread(target=requests.get, args=(apiurl,))
      thread.start()
      threads.append(thread)

t2 = time.time()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print("Total time required to process a file - {} Secs".format(t2-t1))
```

- As there are 20K records, would it start 20K threads? OR `OS`/`Python` will handle it? If yes, can we restrict it?
- How can I collect the response returned by `requests.get`?
- Would t2 - t1 really give mw the time required to process whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As there are 20K records, would it start 20K threads? OR OS/Python will handle it? If yes, can we restrict it?

Yes - it will start a thread for each iteration. The maximum amount of threads is dependent on your `OS`.

> How can I grab the response returned by requests.get?

If you want to use the `threading` module only, you'll have to make use of a `Queue`. `Threads` return `None` by design, hence you'll have to implement a line of communication between the `Thread` and you `main` loop yourself.

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time

# A thread that produces data
q = Queue()



def return_get(q, apiurl):
    q.put(requests.get(apiurl)

for record in file_data_obj:
    apiurl = https://www.api-server.com?id=record.get("acc_id", "")
    t = threading.Thread(target=return_get, args=(q, apiurl))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

while not q.empty:
    r = q.get()  # Fetches the first item on the queue
    print(r.text)
```

An alternative is to use a worker pool.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from queue import Queue
import urllib.request

threads = []

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)

# Submit work to the pool
for record in file_data_obj:
    apiurl = https://www.api-server.com?id=record.get("acc_id", "")
    t = pool.submit(fetch_url, 'http://www.python.org')
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    print(t.result())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)

Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents

```
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()
```

Create pool executor with N workers

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N_workers) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```